# Submitting multi-stage form using .load method

Tags: jquery

I've been looking at this multi-stage form at http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/89/ and was just wondering about the best way of submitting the form using the .load method.

I've been trying this so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#last-step").hide(300).show(300).$load("resources/process.php", 
$("#task5_booking").serialize());
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Few typos on your code.

- $.post chained with previous statements
- Sending a post request with serialized data in the wrong way.

Update your code like this

```
$("#last-step").hide(300).show(300);
$.post(
   "resources/process.php",
   { data: $("#task5_booking").serialize() }
);
```

Comment: the last comma might give problems

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("#last-step").hide(300).show(300);
$.load(
   "resources/process.php",
   { data: $("#task5_booking").serialize() }
);
}
</script>` I have this and keep getting errors.

Comment: @Starx I accidently put **.post** when it was meant to be **.load**.

Comment: @methusaleh, Can you show a demo of your issue, on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $("#last-step").hide(300,function(){
    $.post("resources/process.php", { data : $("#task5_booking").serialize()} ,function(result){
        $("#last-step").html(result).fadeIn(500);
   });
 });
});
```

This will initially hide the last-step div and then submit the jQuery post and once it gets the result it set the result to that div and applies a `fadeIn` effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a POST via `load()`, use `serializeArray()` rather than `serialize()`.

`serialize()` returns a string, whereas serializeArray returns an object.
`load()` sends a POST request if the data is an object. If data is a string, `load()` sends a GET.